# What is the simplest way to get the second item of each row in a string file

Tags: vb.net

I have a String file with 8 items (separated by commas) in each row, e.g., CA,23456,aName,aType,anotherName,aWord,secondword,number. I want to create a new string of items consisting of the 2nd item (an Integer) of each row of the original file. I know there are many ways to do this but someone out there knows how to do it with very few lines of code, which is what I am looking for. I prefer not to use a parser.

The way to show what I have tried is to look at the code below.

```
    Dim sn2 As String = ""
    Dim sn2S As String = ""
    Using readFile As New StreamReader(newFile1)
        Do While readFile.Peek() <> -1
            sn2S = readFile.ReadLine(1)
            sn2 = sn2 & sn2S & ","
        Loop
    End Using
```

The code returns the second character of each row not the second item. What I hope to get is a string that looks like: 123,1345,4325,3321,3456,3211 etc. Where each number is the second item in each row of the original file.

Comment: Split the string and get second item from it, such as splitstringarray()=myline.split then something = splitstringarray(1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In one line

```
Dim sn2 = String.Join(",", File.ReadAllLines(newFile1).Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c)(1)))
```

From the inside-out:

1. `File.ReadAllLines(newFile1)` splits the file into lines and results in a string array holding those lines, which is fed into...
2. `...Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c)(1))` which operates on each line by splitting the line by comma `s.Split(","c)` and then indexing the resulting array `(1)` to return the second (zero-based) element. This is fed into...
3. `String.Join(",", ... )` which takes those second elements and joins then together with comma.

Comment: I am not sure of how it works but it does. Great!! Thanks

Comment: Great explanation. Are there any books or articles that I could read to educate myself on this kind of LINQ ? code.

Comment: @EdJenkins personally, I learn mainly by doing, and some StackOverflow browsing. Good luck!

Comment: Could your code be modified to start reading at line 7 (not line 0) ? I have a need to remove the first 7 lines of my CSV file for another project.

Comment: @EdJenkins `String.Join(",", File.ReadAllLines(newFile1).Skip(7).Select(Function(s) s.Split(","c)(1)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could split it up by cells

```
    Dim row As String = "CA,23456,aName,aType,anotherName,aWord,secondword,number"

    Dim cells() As String = row.Split(",")
    Dim cellValue As String = cells(1)
```

But in your case, I would just do a search and Substring by the index of the delimiter.

```
    Dim startPosition As Integer = row.IndexOf(",") + 1
    Dim endPosition As Integer = row.IndexOf(",", startPosition)
    Dim cellValue As String = row.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition)
```

If you have the whole file in memory, there could be some regex that could do the job with one pass.

As for this line

```
    sn2 = sn2 & sn2S & ","
```

You might want to check at doing a join or using stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 Dim sn2 As String = ""
 Dim sn2S(7) As String = ""
    Using readFile As New StreamReader(newFile1)
        Do While readFile.Peek() <> -1
            Array.Clear(sn25,0,sn25.Length)
            sn2S = readFile.ReadLine(1).Split(",")
            sn2 = sn2 & sn2S(1) & ","
        Loop
    End Using
```